# How do I add numbers from a list of user inputs?

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program where it will tell you:

1. The number of integers in a list entered by the user at the command prompt
2. The sum of those integers.

But I'm having some trouble figuring out how to access those individual numbers. I've tried writing the while loop already, as well as the "if" statements.

Another issue I'm having is that when I try to run my program, I get this error message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed.

NOTE: I'm very new to Java so a simpler solution that mainly uses scanners, next methods, and hasNext methods would be better!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class InputParser
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("How many values do you want to parse?: ");
      int numValues = scanner.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Please enter " + numValues + " values: ");

      while(scanner.hasNextLine())
      {
         if(scanner.hasNext())
         {
            if(scanner.hasNextInt())
            {
               int sum;

               System.out.println("The sum of your values is: " + sum + ".");
            }
         }  
         scanner.close();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You can just store each number in an arraylist and then sum all elements in the arraylist after you are done acquiring numbers.

Comment: Oh! Maybe I'm using the wrong word, what I meant by "command prompt" was that the user enters the values on the Terminal window. Sorry, still pretty new to programming!

Comment: And this is probably a stupid question, but how would I store each number in an array?? I know how to iterate through arrays and get the total that way, but how would I store the number(s)??

Comment: Move scanner.close outside the loop to get rid of the error

Comment: Your code runs like this: you enter something; scanner tests if it has next line, next something and next int, then you print something, then the scanner closes. And then, after the scanner has closed, you test if it has a next line again. That's the source of your Exception.

Comment: Hmm, so if I move the scanner.close outside of the while loop, it just keeps printing out the same thing over and over again when I go to run it. :( Infinite loop.

Comment: @Karen for saving your data do you need to use array ?

Comment: @Karen how many numbers do you need to read? is there any stopping point to read your numbers? like when you type x scanner stop reading

Comment: @KickButtowski: It'll depend on how many the user wants to enter. And nope, no stopping point.

Comment: @Karen so reading numbers goes forever?

Comment: @KickButtowski: Hmm, I believe you'll just read whatever the user inputs. So if the user wants to input an especially long list, then we'll have to read all of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62304/discussion-between-kick-buttowski-and-karen).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you would ask the user how many numbers they want to sum ahead of time. Basically, your code can be simplified and handle an arbitrary number of numbers. It's also a *really bad idea* to call `close()` on a `Scanner` wrapping `System.in` (Because you can't re-open it, and if you extract it into a method you will create a hard to debug and find issue). Anyway, you could do something like,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
// System.out.print("How many values do you want to parse?: ");
// int numValues = scanner.nextInt();
System.out.println("Please enter values to sum (type quit to stop)");
int sum = 0; // <-- start at 0.
int count = 0;
while (scanner.hasNext()) {
    if (scanner.hasNextInt()) {
        count++;
        sum += scanner.nextInt();
    } else {
        String str = scanner.next();
        if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
            break; // <-- end the loop.
        }
        System.out.printf("The value '%s' is not an int (quit to stop).%n", str);
    }
}
System.out.printf("The sum of your %d values is %d.%n", count, sum);
// scanner.close(); // <-- Really Bad Idea
```

**Edit** Based on your comment,

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter values to sum (type quit to stop)");
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String str = scanner.nextLine();
    str = (str != null) ? str.trim() : "";
    if (str.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {
        break; // <-- end the loop.
    } else if (str.length() == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    int sum = 0; // <-- start at 0.
    int count = 0;
    Scanner scan2 = new Scanner(str);
    while (scan2.hasNextInt()) {
        count++;
        sum += scan2.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.printf("The sum of your %d values is %d.%n", count, sum);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about scanner.close(), I didn't realize it was a bad thing to put it here. Sorry, really new to Java. But thanks for your answer! Really helps.

Comment: @Karen Normally, closing the `scanner` would be fine. Unfortunately, `System.in` is a global variable and calling `scanner.close()` also calls `System.in.close()`.

Comment: What if I want the program to start adding/counting the integers once the user hits "enter" on their keyboard? (i.e. After the user enters a list like this: 1 2 3 4, they hit "enter" and the last statement is printed out)

Comment: @Karen You could read in the entire line (with `nextLine()`) and then use a [`new Scanner(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.lang.String%29) to parse the `int` values (as I demonstrated in my answer).

Comment: Ah, so I change "scanner.hasNext()" in the while loop to "scanner.hasnextLine()", and then...do you think you could show me how to use the new Scanner(String)? So sorry, it just helps me to see an example. :/

Comment: @Karen Edited to demonstrate.

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like:

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("How many values do you want to parse?: ");
  int numValues = scanner.nextInt();
  int[] values = new int(numValues);
  int sum = 0,i=0;
  while(i<numValues)
  {  i++;
     System.out.print("Enter "+ i+" number : ");
     values[i-1] = scanner.nextInt();
     sum+= values[i-1];
  }
  System.out.println("Sum is : "+sum);
  scanner.close();
```

Haven't really consider error handling.

Comment: how many number your scanner reads?

Comment: Ah, I see what you did. And if I want to count how many integers are in the list (suppose the user can enter a list of integers/doubles), what would that look like?? You mentioned saving the numbers into an array I believe?

Comment: This code is just for integer please try for double your self. if you get stuck then ask. Please check the edit for the storing the values in array